# How to return textpositions in PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want to get the text position of each character of a pdf document. I have looked at the `PrintTextLocations` example provided by PDFBox example site. In that example, they have overridden the protected `writeString` method and print the text positions by extending the `PDFTextStripper` class. Here is that method

```
/**
 * Override the default functionality of PDFTextStripper.
 */
@Override
protected void writeString(String string, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException
{
    for (TextPosition text : textPositions)
    {
        System.out.println( "String[" + text.getXDirAdj() + "," +
                text.getYDirAdj() + " fs=" + text.getFontSize() + " xscale=" +
                text.getXScale() + " height=" + text.getHeightDir() + " space=" +
                text.getWidthOfSpace() + " width=" +
                text.getWidthDirAdj() + "]" + text.getUnicode() );
    }
}
```

But I want to return the `TextPosition` list from the class. From the API I have found out that there is a protected method in `PDFTextStripper` class named `getCharactersByArticle()` which returns `protected List<List<TextPosition>>`.

I want to know how to return the list from the method.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: *return the list from the method* - You want to return it from *which* method? Obviously not `writeString` as you aren't the caller and the actual callers would ignore any returns.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following workaround if memory isn't a problem for your code.

```
static ArrayList<TextPosition> pos=new ArrayList<TextPosition>();
/**
 * Override the default functionality of PDFTextStripper.
 */
@Override
protected void writeString(String string, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException
{
    for (TextPosition text : textPositions)
    {
        pos.add(text);
        System.out.println( "String[" + text.getXDirAdj() + "," +
            text.getYDirAdj() + " fs=" + text.getFontSize() + " xscale=" +
            text.getXScale() + " height=" + text.getHeightDir() + " space=" +
            text.getWidthOfSpace() + " width=" +
            text.getWidthDirAdj() + "]" + text.getUnicode() );
    }
}
```

or, You could copy the pdfbox classes and rebuid in your project with the desired changes.